# How to open specific activity of Microsoft SharePoint App in Android from my application?

Tags: android, sharepoint

I want to open Dev Site or other  Screen of Microsoft SharePoint Android App from another Android App ( Kotlin / Java).

Now only able to open the app, not able to redirect it to the Dev Site or other  Screen of Microsoft SharePoint App.

When I try to open any other Activiy of Microsoft SharePoint App from another Android app, the app force closed .

The below code shows that we are able to open Microsoft share point app from another app.

```
 Intent intent =
 getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.microsoft.sharepoint");
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); startActivity(intent);
```

But below code crashed when we are try to open another screen of SharePoint App

*DESIRED_ACTIVITY = Any other screen of the SharePoint App

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.setClassName("com.microsoft.sharepoint",
 "com.microsoft.sharepoint.DESIRED_ACTIVITY");
 startActivity(intent);
```

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

[Working Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIZx8.png)

[Required flow which not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIzbz.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following 2 options: -

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.microsoft.sharepoint", "com.microsoft.sharepoint.DESIRED_ACTIVITY"));
startActivity(intent);
```

OR

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.microsoft.sharepoint", "com.microsoft.sharepoint.DESIRED_ACTIVITY");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hi,
But still the proble is there ...  android:exported="false"


Actually what i saw over code that in androidmanifest.xml file 


 <activity android:name="com.microsoft.sharepoint.DESIRED_ACTIVITY"
            android:exported="false"/>

Comment: If export=false, then they don't want to allow other application to launch this activity.